# I get a block that doesn't change on other pages

Tags: views

I have an issue with the contextual filters when I use *Content: ID*. On the site I get a repetitive, when there are many more recipes.

The block remains the same, with two recipes, which is fine, but they don't change on another page. It's always the same.

I hope this makes sense.

> [image: Recipes]

> [image: Block]

> [image: Contextual Filter]

> [image: Recipes]

> [image: Main Issue]

Comment: You're only getting two items because you've set your View to only display two items. You're getting those two because you're sorting by creation date desc. Those must be the last two created. When you add more recipes, those will show up instead. I don't know what you're using the contextual filter for.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! As @beltouche said, the block is set to show the last two created recipes. Since there aren't other restrictions, such as "don't show the link for the currently viewed node," that block will show the same two links for every page where the block is shown, until a new recipe is created. You also added the contextual filter, but the view isn't using it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much! Yes the contextual filters with ID is now working.